# No output PDF file produced!

Tags: pdftex, pdf, acm

From time to time while I am editing my ACM sigconf template, I get this error. With adding/removing some text (e.g. section), the error disappear but it happens so frequently that I need to find a permanent solution.

```
Error: pdfTeX error (ext4): \pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than \pdfstartlink. sample-sigconf.tex(1): Error:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I looked at all the previous posts with similar errors. Solution are centered around that there might be a link broken and this can be solved by adding: `\usepackage{hyperref}`

This does not solve the problem for me. Please, do not mark this post as duplicate as non of the solutions helped me.

P.S. Because the issue is tailored to my original text, I can not post my original text. If I changed the number of paragraphs, it disappear. All what I can post is the template and packages that I'm working on:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %to solve the font error
\usepackage{lmodern}  %to solve the font error
\usepackage{epstopdf} %convert eps to pdf
\usepackage{placeins} %for \FloatBarrier before references
\usepackage{underscore} %for underscoresent
\usepackage{hyperref}

%-------------------------for the table-----------------------------
\usepackage{colortbl}       
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable, tablefootnote}

%---------- for diagram requires msc package -------------------
\usepackage{msc} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''} %for qoutation marks
%--------------------------------------------------------------

% Copyright
%\setcopyright{none}
%\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
%\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
\setcopyright{rightsretained}
%\setcopyright{usgov}
%\setcopyright{usgovmixed}
%\setcopyright{cagov}
%\setcopyright{cagovmixed}


% DOI
\acmDOI{10.475/123_4}

% ISBN
\acmISBN{123-4567-24-567/08/06}

%Conference
\acmConference[AAA 2017]{ACM Conf.}{2017}{USA} 
\acmYear{2017}
\copyrightyear{2017}

\acmPrice{15.00}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\author{Author}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Instit}}
\email{aaa@abc.com}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract here. 
\end{abstract}


\section{Section 1}
Section.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is the `msc` package, what do you need it for?

Comment: @daleif msc is a package for drawing message sequence diagrams. I used it before with other templates and no such error ever appeared. How did you know it is because of it? Also, the error disappear when I comment a text section. It works with the msc diagram.

Comment: No idea, `mcs` is still doing stuff that does not seem compatible with `pdflatex`. Are you sure you are filling in the `amc` macros correctly? I have no experince with it.

Comment: Just started over, basically remove the aux files etc. I no longer get any error with this. But get some non-pdf warnings, from msc. Exactly which latex installation are you using? I'm on TeXLive 2017.

Comment: I am using MikTex 2.9.6300. I deleted everything. It did not solve the problem.

Comment: The `mcs` package is using pstricks which might not work correctly using pdflatex (there are some methods to get it to work, but you do not seem to load any of them). I don't think I can help you further

Comment: @user6875880: I've just encountered a problem similar to yours, merging old repositories together and then trying to compile some Beamer presentation files. In case this could help, in my case, the error message appeared because of an inconsistent `\includeonlyframes{}` command, with frames that did not belong to the presentation any more. Removing that command did the trick.